# c, printf, double: getting more than 15 decimal digits

Tags: c, double, ieee-754

I am implementing a simple algorithm to estimate the sqrt of a double in c, similar to how I learned to do it in java.

However, when I use printf("Current guess: %.30f \n", guess); to print my current guess, I'm actually getting 30 digits of the double. I was under the impression that due to IEEE, a double can only have 15 decimal digits? Where are these numbers coming from?

My full code:

```
int main() {
// Finding the sqrt of x
double x = 1337.;
double high = x;
double low = 0.;
double guess;
double lastguess = -1.;
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    lastguess = guess;
    guess = low+(high-low)/2;
    if(compDouble(guess, lastguess)) {
        break;
    }
    if(guess*guess > x) {
        // Guess was too high
        // get the lower interval
        low = low;
        high = guess;
    } else {
        // Guess was too low, get the upper interval
        low = guess;
        high = high;
    }
    printf("Current guess: %.30f \n", guess);
}
printf("sqrt of %f is about %f", x, guess);
return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
Current guess: 668.500000000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 334.250000000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 167.125000000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 83.562500000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 41.781250000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 20.890625000000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 31.335937500000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.558593750000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 39.169921875000000000000000000000 
Current guess: 37.864257812500000000000000000000 
Current guess: 37.211425781250000000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.885009765625000000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.721801757812500000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.640197753906250000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.599395751953125000000000000000 
Current guess: 36.578994750976562500000000000000 
Current guess: 36.568794250488281250000000000000 
Current guess: 36.563694000244140625000000000000 
Current guess: 36.566244125366210937500000000000 
Current guess: 36.564969062805175781250000000000 
Current guess: 36.565606594085693359375000000000 
Current guess: 36.565287828445434570312500000000 
Current guess: 36.565128445625305175781250000000 
Current guess: 36.565048754215240478515625000000 
Current guess: 36.565008908510208129882812500000 
Current guess: 36.565028831362724304199218750000 
Current guess: 36.565018869936466217041015625000 
Current guess: 36.565013889223337173461914062500 
Current guess: 36.565011398866772651672363281250 
Current guess: 36.565010153688490390777587890625 
Current guess: 36.565010776277631521224975585938 
Current guess: 36.565010464983060956001281738281 
Current guess: 36.565010620630346238613128662109 
Current guess: 36.565010542806703597307205200195 
Current guess: 36.565010581718524917960166931152 
Current guess: 36.565010601174435578286647796631 
Current guess: 36.565010591446480248123407363892 
Current guess: 36.565010596310457913205027580261 
Current guess: 36.565010598742446745745837688446 
Current guess: 36.565010597526452329475432634354 
Current guess: 36.565010598134449537610635161400 
Current guess: 36.565010597830450933543033897877 
Current guess: 36.565010597678451631509233266115 
Current guess: 36.565010597602451980492332950234 
Current guess: 36.565010597564452154983882792294 
sqrt of 1337.000000 is about 36.565011
```

Comment: 'Due to IEEE, a double can only have 15 decimal digits': false: a double can only have 15 decimal digits of *integral* precision. After the decimal point, anything goes, right up to infinity.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne: If an IEEE-754 binary64 `double` can only have 15 decimal digits of precision, how come 1000000000000001, which has 16 digits, is represented exactly?

Answer (score 3):

> I was under the impression that due to IEEE, a double can only have 15 decimal digits?

Well, that's wrong.

Try this:

```
double d = 1.0e-45;
printf("d is %.60f \n", d);
```

output:

```
d is 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000
```

As you see there is much more than 15 decimal digits.

The number of decimal digits depends on the value of the number. Very small numbers can have very many decimal digits (with a lot of zero first) while very large number can't have any decimal digits at all. Some very large numbers can't even represent odd numbers.

The smallest non-zero (positive) value that a standard 64 bit double can have is 2<sup>-1074</sup> which is:

```
0.000......04940656.............47265625
            ^                          ^
            |                          |
            Decimal digit #324         Decimal digit #1074
```

Try it using this code:

```
int main(void)
{
  assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t));

  union
  {
    uint64_t i;
    double d;
  } x;

  x.i = 1;  // The smallest non-zero positive double value
  printf("%.1100f \n", x.d);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that due to IEEE, a double can only have 15 decimal digits?

This is incorrect. When the IEEE-754 binary64 format is used for `double`, a number is represented with 53 binary digits (bits) for the significand (the “fraction” portion of the floating-point number) along with a sign and a power of two (the exponent). Each binary64 number represents one specific number exactly, and they are not spaced evenly relative to decimal numerals.

For a simple example, consider numbers with the significand 1 but varying exponents. For example, consider +1•2<sup>0</sup> (sign +, significand 1, exponent 0). In decimal this is “1”, just one digit. Then +1•2<sup>−1</sup> is “.5”, still just one significant digit. +1•2<sup>−2</sup> is “.25”. This has two significant digits even though its significand is just one. Following this are “.125”, “.0625”, “0.03125”, and so on. As you can see, the number of significant digits needed for the number in decimal grows even though the significand is still 1.

Thus, the number of decimal digits needed to represent a binary64 number depends both on the significand and the exponent.

We can calculate how many decimal digits a number around 36 might require. Because 10 has one factor of two, each decrease (to greater negative values) in the exponent of a binary64 can require one more decimal position to represent: In 0.5, the last digit is in the 10<sup>−1</sup> position. In .25, it is in the 10<sup>−2</sup> position, in .125, it is in the 10<sup>−3</sup> position, and so on.

To represent a number around 36, a binary64 must use an exponent of 5, so that the highest bit of the significand (which is usually normalized to be between 1 and 2, including 1 but excluding 2) is scaled to 32. Then, in the scaled number, the bits in the significand represent 2<sup>5</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>3</sup>,… 2<sup>5−52</sup>. That least significant bit, 2<sup>5−52</sup>, is 2<sup>−47</sup>.

Therefore, some binary64 numbers around 36, when represented in decimal will have two digits left of the decimal point and 47 to the right of it, so they will have 49 significant decimal digits.

The binary64 format allows exponents down to −1022, at which point the least significant bit of the significand is scaled to −1022−52 = −1074, so representing the smallest positive binary64 value in decimal requires 1074 digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

IEEE DOUBLE has about 16 *significant* digits.  That is, if you look at a string of decimal digits representing a DOUBLE, any digits after about the first 16 will be 'garbage'.  (I'm ignoring leading zeros.)

So, sure, you can *display* 30 digits.  But only the first half can be trusted.

Continue studying square root; there is a simple algorithm that converges quadratically; yours seems to be linear.